# Flutter NullSafety cannot push Page after showing and change modalProgressHUD

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety

I'm using Provider package to expose a simple boolean variabile that allow to change the status of variable "inAsyncCall" of the ModalProgressHUD widget.

When i try to do somethings before navigate to another page, and i want to display the circlular progress indicator during that computation, when the Future terminated, the current widget has been disposed and i cannot use Navigator.push():

```
Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
```

this is my Provider with ChangeNotifier class:

```
class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  bool _inAsync = false;

  bool get inAsync => _inAsync;

  void setInAsync(bool flag) {
    this._inAsync = flag;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I inject the provider before the MaterialApp widget like this:

```
 void main() async {
   runApp(App());
 }

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => CartProvider(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the simple home page where i access via context the provider injected:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cartProvider = context.watch<CartProvider>();
    return ModalProgressHUD(
      inAsyncCall: cartProvider.inAsync,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('HOME'),
              FirstStatefulWidget(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: SecondStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FirstStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FirstStatefulWidgetState createState() => _FirstStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _FirstStatefulWidgetState extends State<FirstStatefulWidget> {
  late CartProvider cartProvider = context.read<CartProvider>();

  Future doSomething() async {
    cartProvider.setInAsync(true);
    await Future.delayed(
      Duration(seconds: 2),
      () => {
        cartProvider.setInAsync(false),
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
          ),
        )
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('do call'),
        onPressed: doSomething,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SecondStatefulWidgetState createState() => _SecondStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _SecondStatefulWidgetState extends State<SecondStatefulWidget> {
  late CartProvider cartProvider = context.read<CartProvider>();

  void goToAnotherPageAfterCall() async {
    try {
      cartProvider.setInAsync(true);
      Future.delayed(
        Duration(seconds: 2),
        () => {
          cartProvider.setInAsync(false),
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => SecondPage(),
            ),
          )
        },
      );
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      cartProvider.setInAsync(false);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('goToAnotherPage'),
        onPressed: goToAnotherPageAfterCall,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```